# svf conversion form 3d model

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Hi i need to convert a fbx file to svf

i tried to convert with https://extract.autodesk.io/ but i havent a svf file

the thing is i want to use this viewer :

https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/viewer-javascript-offline.sample

[image]

this the result i need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are successfully extracted the file, it's not only one svf file, but will be bunch of files together as shown in the following picture, and you just need to copy all these files under your server, and just use the file path of the svf file.

[image]

Comment: i succeed i just did'nt saw the svf file in the model directory. thank you !:)